# Automated web testing using selenium help needed

Tags: css, testing, selenium

I'm using selenium to test a web application but need some help.
One of the nodes that needs to be clicked has a constant changing value on startup.

Example:

click css=#f0012 > ins.jstree-icon

On startup the letter before 0012 is randomly assigned (a letter from a-z). This means each time my selemnium script is run, I need to somehow obtain this character or just reference the 0012 so that the program knows which button to click.

I'm really stuck on this so would appreciate any help

Comment: ,First thing, if the button is in DOM, you can get it clicked for sure. But to tell you the easiest way, Show us some HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
click css=[id$='0012'] > ins.jstree-icon
```

The `$=` will look for elements that end in "0012".